# Вид кнопки сворачивания Меню, Бутстрап 4

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Вот что у меня получается:

[image: кнопка сворачивания почти не видна]

Вот что должно получиться:

[image: тут это стандартная бургер иконка из трёх горизонтальных черт]

Что не так?

Вот мой код -

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">      
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">        
                <img src="https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/assets/img/og.dd30b10.png" alt="BS-logo" width="40" height="40">
            </a>         
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">      
                <span class="navbar-toggler-item"></span>      
            </button>        
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">     
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">     
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                    </li>    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
                    </li>        
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About us</a>
                    </li>        
                </ul>        
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">        
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="search" aria-label="Search">        
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Search</button>        
                </form>        
            </div>        
        </nav>        
        <h1>Kotiki, kotiki, probujut narkotiki!</h1>
```

Comment: Оформите код правильно, читать невозможно)

Comment: Я пытаюсь, но как?? Я ставлю энтеры после каждой строки, а оно не отображается как перенос строки.

Answer (score 0):

У вас скорее всего не подключены js и css файлы bootstrap.
Добавьте в ваш файл ссылки

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Помните bootstrap требует установки jquery. Так что ссылки на jquery должны так же присутствовать.

Comment: Всё подключил.
Вот в тэге Хэд:
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
Вот перед закрывающим Боди:
https://www.screencast.com/t/LT09wPuCcaY0

Comment: Вот ваш код с подключенными библиотеками пример https://jsfiddle.net/2drhqpws/1/

Comment: @zhl у вас на скрине отсутствует файл стилей bootstrap

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/QVHnUGLU это тоже есть

Comment: Проверяйте лучше. Проблема однозначно со стилями.